# Saving preferences VIM

Tags: vim

Hi I'm a new user to vim text editor (love it) and would like to save my preferences in VIM ie font and size and background colour, ive searched and the only things i can find say modify the rc file however they do not specify how except to advise on customisations such as line spacing. Please could someone advise?

Answer (score 1):

On a Linux machine, you can start making a `.vimrc` file in your home folder by running the following in the terminal:

```sh
vim ~/.vimrc
```

This is the "*rc*" file that they are talking about.

Regarding the formatting of this file, you can put every setting on a separate line:

```
" This line is a comment, the following 2 lines are settings:
colorscheme desert
set history=500
```

While still in `vim`, save with `:wq`.
The next time you start `vim`, it will use the settings that you just specified in your `~/.vimrc`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the `$ vimtutor` section dedicated to that very subject:

```
                      Lesson 7.2: CREATE A STARTUP SCRIPT


                          ** Enable Vim features **

  Vim has many more features than Vi, but most of them are disabled by
  default.  To start using more features you have to create a "vimrc" file.

  1. Start editing the "vimrc" file.  This depends on your system:
        :e ~/.vimrc             for Unix
        :e ~/_vimrc             for Windows

  2. Now read the example "vimrc" file contents:
        :r $VIMRUNTIME/vimrc_example.vim

  3. Write the file with:
        :w

  The next time you start Vim it will use syntax highlighting.
  You can add all your preferred settings to this "vimrc" file.
  For more information type  :help vimrc-intro
```